# Find next increment value in array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array:

```
var array = [2,4,5,8,11];
```

I need to get next increment value so in above example i need to get:

```
 1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13 ....
```

How can i do that in javascript?

Comment: loop + math = solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can create a new array where you can store the desired values. Then loop (in this case from 0 to 15) and check if the number is in the `array`-array. If it is not in the array, you can store the value in the `values`-array.

```js
var array = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11];
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  if (!array.includes(i))
    values.push(i);
}

console.log(values); // Output: [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this method using `includes()`.its same as you like

1. Create the  number's with while loop without included array value

```js
var array = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11];
var i = 0;
while (i < 20) {
  if (!array.includes(i)) {
    console.log(i)
  }
  i++
}
```